# What to use to move UIView self.frame or self.transform property?

Tags: ios, view, properties

I'm a little confused this question.

I know that I can move views changing their `self.frame.origin`, but I found that there is a property called transform and I thought that this is for moving my view on the screen and etc.
Maybe I don't understand that a little.

So I want to know: which property I must use for moving `UIView` (or it's subclasses) and for what is another one?
Or if I'm completely wrong show me the right way please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `frame` property of a `UIView` defines it's position relative to it's superview. If you want to move a view, that's the way to go.

The `transform` property basically applies a `CGAffineTransform` to the backing layer of the view. In most cases you don't want to use this property if you just want to move the view.

The `transform` property is useful when it comes to rotating or scaling the layer (i.e. view). Sometimes, when you apply a rotation, you also need to move it to make it "keep" it's postion, in that case you would use the `transform` property to move it.

Comment: Oh, now I see, so `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y)` it's not what you want if you want to move UIView. Thanks your answer helped me to figure that out. Thanks. PS there is typo in your answer `CGAffineTransform`.

Answer (score 6):

To add more information

Why use frame. Quoted from [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1)

> You typically modify the transform property of a view when you want to
>   implement animations. For example, you could use this property to
>   create an animation of your view rotating around its center point. **You
>   would not use this property to make permanent changes to your view**,
>   such as modifying its position or size a view within its superview’s
>   coordinate space. For that type of change, you should modify the frame
>   rectangle of your view instead

Why use transform. Quoted from [Demystifying CGAffineTransform](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html)

> Translation is just a fancy way of saying "moving". You can, of
>   course, accomplish a move by changing the origin value of the view's
>   frame property (which moves the view in relation to its superview),
>   but since we **can't use the frame property along with other
>   transformations**, the translate transformation is an important one.

Answer (score 5):

You can move a UIView by updating its frame.  Transform is used to rotate and scale the view.  If you want to move the view in an animated manner, try using an animation block like the one below:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 //Time for the animation
                             animations:^{
                               myView.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,10,20) //Move your frame
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                //Do stuff when the animation completes
                             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGrect = rect1 = [view1 frame];

rect1.origin.x = newX;
rect1.origin.y = newY;
```

you must use setFrame in animations:`^{ <here> }`

```
[view1 set enter code here Frame:rect1];
```