# How to add drag to move function to a transformed view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I made a custom view which can be resized and rotated by dragging a corner circle button.

I need the view to be able to drag to change its position.

I tried several ways but none worked property( the view just acts strangely when combining rotation and resize actions).

What is a proper way to do this?

According to this answer quoting apple's document, [What to use to move UIView self.frame or self.transform property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177409/what-to-use-to-move-uiview-self-frame-or-self-transform-property)
I should not use frame property along with transformation so I assume I need to user CGAffineTransform to change position of the view?
(I tried this but did not work well)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ResizeRotateView: UIImageView, Resizable {

private let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 40
private var themeColor: UIColor = UIColor.magentaColor()


// Rotation Resize
var radian: CGFloat = 0

private var tempAnglePanStart  : Float = 0
private var tempAngleLastPanEnd: Float = 0


// UI Subviews
lazy var cornerButton: UIView = {
    let b = UIView()
    
    b.layer.cornerRadius = self.buttonWidth / 2
    b.layer.borderWidth  = 1
    b.layer.borderColor  = self.themeColor.CGColor
    
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTouchMoved) )
    b.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    
    return b
}()




// Init

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    setupSuviews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func setupSuviews() {
    addSubview( cornerButton )
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(\(buttonWidth))]", views: cornerButton)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(\(buttonWidth))]", views: cornerButton)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerButton, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}


override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? { // This will enable gesture out of self.view's boundary. From stackoverflow.

    if let result = super.hitTest(point, withEvent:e) {
        return result
    }
    
    for sub in self.subviews.reverse() {
        let pt = self.convertPoint(point, toView:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, withEvent:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}







////// Event

func buttonTouchMoved(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
 
    resize(gestureRecognizer)
    rotate(gestureRecognizer)
}
 







////// Action

// Resize
func resize(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
 
    // Temporary set aglet to 0
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 0 )

    // Resize
    let locationInSelf = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)

    resizeByKeepingAspectRatioByDistanceFromCenter(toLocation: locationInSelf)
    layoutSubviews()

    // Recover angle
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( radian )
    layoutSubviews()
    
}



// Rotation
func rotate(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    guard let superView = self.superview else {
        print("#Error: Super View not found")
        return
    }
    
    let angle = self.angle(byLocation: gestureRecognizer.locationInView( superView ) )
    
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
        print("Pan begin:\(angle)")
        tempAnglePanStart = angle - tempAngleLastPanEnd
    }
    
    
    let destinationAngle = angle - tempAnglePanStart
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( destinationAngle.degreesToRadians )
    
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .Ended {
        print("Pan ended")
        tempAngleLastPanEnd = destinationAngle
    }
}













////// Helper

func angle( firstPoint: CGPoint, secondPoint: CGPoint ) -> Float {
    
    let dx = firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x
    let dy = firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y
    let angle = atan2(dy, dx).radiansToDegrees
    let angleInFloat = Float( angle.double )
    
    let formattedAngle = angleInFloat < 0 ? angleInFloat + 360.0 : angleInFloat
    
    return formattedAngle
}


func angle(byLocation location: CGPoint) -> Float {
    
    let targetViewCnter = self.center
    return self.angle(targetViewCnter, secondPoint: location)
}

func setAngle(angle: Float) {
    let radian = angle.degreesToRadians
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( radian )
    self.radian = radian
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

### Update

I came very close.  I could move by keeping rotation angle and view's size.  The remaining problem is view jumps a bit when I start dragging.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ResizeRorateMovableView: ResizeRotateView {

    var startCenter: CGPoint = CGPointZero
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setupSuviews()
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureEvent))
        addGestureRecognizer( panGesture )
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    func panGestureEvent(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if panGesture.state == .Began {
            self.startCenter = self.center
            return
        }
        
        if panGesture.state == .Changed {
            
            let location = panGesture.translationInView(self)
            
            // Rotate first, then move
            var transfrom  = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( self.radian )
            transfrom      = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transfrom, location.x, location.y)
            self.transform = transfrom

            return
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that most apps use a pan gesture to move, not rotate like you are doing. Consider that the many users are used to (a) pan gestures move a view, (b) pinch gestures resize a view, and (c) rotate gestures rotate a view. With what you are coding, you may almost need a completely different mechanism to code - something like a distinct action to begin/end rotating and another distinct action to begin/end moving.

Comment: Even though an event triggers a transformation is different, actual transformation is done by same logic so I guess that doesn't matter.

I also plan to implement the (a), (b), (c), but one advantage for pan to rotate is that it could be done by one finger that a user can operate the task by one hand.

Comment: could you please check this question here to see if you could help me out? I believe it might be related -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539024/resizing-uiview-using-cgaffinetransform-scale-doesnt-update-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need was just to add a superview to implement move function.

This case, I can completely separate rotation function and move function making it real easy to handle.

- ViewA.  Move function implemented.  It is visible below to make it easy to understand but its color should be clear.  I made touch for move function only enabled on ViewB(the subview).
- ViewB.  Rotation function implemented.  It is a subview of ViewA
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It probably jumps because the user doesn't necessarily touch in the center, but you're setting the center to where they dragged. If you start dragging close to the center, it won't jump as much as if you start dragging close to the edge. To fix, when the gesture begins, get the distance from the touch to the current center and use that offset when making the translation.

Comment: I'm having hard time doing this by using CGAffineTransform translation.  If you could, would you post code please?

Comment: It seems strange jump is not related to the center.  Even if I tap very close to the center, the view jumps a lot more distance than touch point to the center.

Comment: If you can post the code that you have so far in a sample project, I'll take a look.

Comment: I tried number of ways but it seems the code I posted is closest to the solution.

BTW, I came up with an idea to add superview to handle move function.  In this case I don't have to be bothered by CAAffineTransform stuff.  If this didn't work, I'll post the situation again.

Comment: Adding superview to handle move function did work perfectly!  I'll post the code when I have time.  Anyway thank you for your help and I really appreciate.