# Resizing UIView using CGAffineTransform scale doesn't update frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm trying to resize a UIView (Parent) with a few subviews in it using CGAffineTransform scale.
I'm resizing the parent by dragging it from one corner using pan gesture.
The resizing works as expected but if I try to resize it again, it jumps back to the initial frame. It's like it never knew it was resized.

These are the steps I am doing so far:

1.- Just when the pan gesture begins I get the initial frame and the touch location in superview:

```
if gesture.state == .began {
        
        //We get all initial values from the first touch
        initialFrame = self.frame;
        touchStart = gesture.location(in: superview)
    }
```

2.- Then I go to the handle I'm dragging (Top right in this case), set the anchor point, calculate deltas (Initial touch - gesture distance traveled), calculate new frame, scales, and apply transform.

```
    case topRight:
        
        if gesture.state == .began {
            self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
        }

        
        let deltaX = -1 * (touchStart.x - gesture.location(in: superview).x)
        let deltaY = 1 * (touchStart.y - gesture.location(in: superview).y)
        
        let newWidth = initialFrame.width + deltaX;
        let newHeight = initialFrame.height + deltaY;
        
        let scaleX:CGFloat = newWidth / initialFrame.width;
        let scaleY:CGFloat = newHeight / initialFrame.height;

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
```

3.- Finally I reset the anchor point to the middle of the UIView.

```
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
         
 
        }
```

I attached a gif where you can see the UIView is resized from the top right handle. When I try to resize it again, it jumps back to the initial frame. (It seems that the video is restarted, but this is the jump)

[image]

what am I missing? do I need to update something else?
Thank you all!

Comment: Because you are applying the transform to the initial frame, which never changes.

Comment: if you would post some code that would be super helpful @matt Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is actually quite simple, this following line of code was incorrect:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
```

Here I am applying the scaling to the identity transform which is always the original size.

Just by changing this to:

```
self.transform = self.initialTransform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
```

Now I am applying the scaling to the current transform which is always saved when the gesture begins.

```
@objc func handleUserPan(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if gesture.state == .began {
            

            self.initialTransform = self.transform;
            self.touchStart = gesture.location(in: resizableSelf.superview);
        }
        
        switch gesture.view! {
        case self.topRight: //This is just the circle view

            if gesture.state == .began {
                self..setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
            }
            
            
            let deltaX = 1 * (self.touchStart.x - gesture.location(in: superview).x)
            let deltaY = 1 * (self.touchStart.y - gesture.location(in: superview).y)
            
            let newWidth = self.initialFrame.width + deltaX;
            let newHeight = self.initialFrame.height + deltaY;
            
            let scaleX:CGFloat = newWidth / self.initialFrame.width;
            let scaleY:CGFloat = newHeight / self.initialFrame.height;

            self.transform = self.initialTransform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
            
        }
        default:()
        }

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
        self.updateDragHandles()


        if gesture.state == .ended {
            self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this can be helpful for those who would like to scale a UIView similar to like Photoshop does with it's layers. It even works if the subviews were rotated.

Keep in mind that once the view is transformed, you **cannot** set the frame value anymore. That's why by having all views inside a superView is more convenient so it takes care of all resizing.

The goal was to replicate the same behavior that **Photoshop** does when resizing layers.